# Rails on Ubuntu 64bit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am trying to set up a dev machine for rails apps. I am thinking of Ubuntu 64bit. I have experience with Ubuntu 32bit but not 64bit.

Has anyone experienced Ubuntu 64bit with rails? Can you share your experience?

Comment: ruby as well as rails is perfectly able to be run on 64bit machines, have 2 staging and 3 production servers running on ubuntu 10.04/10.10, no problems so far

Comment: @sam-kong Hi,I have just migrated from 32 bit to 64 bit and the application seems to be crashing..Here is my question.Please help if you can.:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699331/thin-server-not-working-on-production-modelive-on-amazon-ec2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no problems running Rails on Ubuntu 10.04 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

The major difference between 32x and 64x systems is memory addressing.

A 32x system can't have more than 3.7(ish)GB of memory.

For any server that runs over 4GB 64x is required.

We've been running 64x Ubuntu with RAILs no problem at DigitalOcean so you shouldn't run into any issues.

Answer (score 1):

We run rails apps internally on Ubuntu Server 8.04 LTS (64-bit). No traps or unexpected pitfalls encountered. Haven't tried any newer versions though.

Answer (score 0):

Very high memory usage was seen on 64bit ubuntu vs. 32. bit

Answer (score 0):

We are working with ruby on rails servers on ubuntu 10.04 64 bits in production mode. High traffic ad great stability.

We use last apache2, ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.1

We are using gems like rmagick, feedzira,etc.. that need special ubuntu libraries.

We migrated from 32 bits without any problem.

I don't want to do any promotion, but in this case a real case is the best answer your question. I include the link http://www.cosasderegalo.com

Also we have a development machine with ubuntu 10.04 64 bits, also we use RVM to manage better different gem sets.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running and using Ubuntu 11.10 64bit as my main OS and am programming with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2.2.

After installing all the necessary gems such as Ruby, Rails and a javascript engine such as Node.js and/or Therubyracer, you just need the individual gems that you personally use.

I have had no problems what so ever, so thoroughly advise it.

If your having any trouble, There is a blog that explains setting up using a Virtual box but the steps are the same for a full installation.